# Fast way to calculate the dot product of two lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I call a for loop about a million times.
In this loop, I want to calculate the dot product of two array-like objects along their last axis.

I have one array `test_arr = np.arange(200).reshape(20, 10)` (this is for reproducing, the actual array is already stored), and a list that I create as `test_list = [np.arange(20)] * 10` (again the object inside the list is already stored, the `arange` is for reproducibility.

Currently, I use

```
 result = np.einsum("ij, ij -> i", test_list, test_arr)
```

This yields an array of shape `20` (as desired) but while this works superbly for large data structures apparently has too much overhead to be called a million times for the small arrays.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dot product of two lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669855/dot-product-of-two-lists-in-python)

Comment: "*I need to calculate the dot product 10 ** 6 times.*" please be more explicit, do you need to compute the **same** thing repeatedly? Why? Also please provide a minimal reproducible example to illustrate what you are doing.

Comment: np.dot (for pre-formed np arrays)  is 50-100x faster than a Python coding (n = 1000) and not much slower for Python Lists. So my question is how do you form the 1M pairs of Lists?

Comment: @user19077881 The problem is that only one of the two array-like objects is an nd-array, the other is a list. The list is formed as `example = [arr_test] * 20`, where `arr_test` is a 1D array. Apparently internally converting the list slows everything down.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you are doing, currently looks like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Also "*while this works superbly for large data structures apparently has too much overhead to be called a million times for the small arrays*" is confusing, this sounds like working on a larger array is faster.

Comment: If it's faster to run it on two numpy arrays, why not make them both numpy arrays? i.e. don't create a list for the second variable but immediately create it as a numpy array to avoid the overhead of converting a list to ndarray.

Comment: @LionCereals, could you use `example = np.tile(arr_test, (20, 1))` (or similar) instead of `example = [arr_test] * 20`? This way, `example` would start out as a numpy array instead of a list of arrays, which should reduce the number of conversions.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp Yeah, that was what I was suggesting.